# iPhoto export shrinks images (and shows inconsistent file properties)

Tags: macos, photos.app

I have several images at 5184 × 3456 (confirmed by the info panel in iPhoto), but when I `Right-Click` + `Show File`, it opens a version in finder that is only 1296 × 864. The path it's taking me to in Finder is obviously not the original.

In iPhoto, I can also zoom in to the actual size, but when exporting, it only exports that smaller size. This is even with the "Original" and "Full Size" options selected in the Export.

How can I simply get the full size image out?

Answer (score 1):

"The path it's taking me to in Finder is obviously not the original." It is taking you to a location that looks like this? [image: Files Location]
Also, Depending on how your exporting may change the characteristics of the file format, hence changing from the "Original" and the original location. [image: iphoto export]
It should also be noted that PhotoStream can change the size of files. For example, if you take a photo with you iPhone and sync via cable to you Mac, but then alter the photo in an iPad using iPhoto, what you get is a different sized file. There's a similar discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3878899?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the path is like: "/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Originals/YEAR/DATE/IMG_NAME.JPG". And from what I can tell, I have "Original" and "Full Size" selected upon export.

Comment: That's what I used to get to, but now have the path I posted. Which version of Mac OS X and iPhoto do you have?

Comment: OS X.7.5 and iPhoto '09 (yeah, I know)